# Extracting vertices in line segments using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, feature-class, vertices, extract

I have ArcGIS Desktop 10.6 and have many polyline features and want to be able to extract the vertices of each line segment that looks like this:

[image: polylines fc]

I want to keep the line ID associated and be able to link the points back to the polyline and also count and order the number of vertices along the polyline...

[image: numbered vertices in order linked to polyline]

[image: line and order example]

Ultimately I want to convert those points to polygons somehow select the inside polygons and delete them to create something like this:

[image]

I see other python scripts here but nothing that does what I need it to do. I've also tried feature to polygon but these FC's are exported out of a third party app and for some reason that tool doesn't work.

So what I have a polyline feature class that looks like a polygon but not closed. I want to extract the vertices along with assocaited line ID and number the vertices per line in order. Take the points shp and create a polygon.

Okay I created a model that works for what I needed...

[image]

Comment: Did you get an error with feature to polygon or why didnt it work? Try setting a larger cluster tolerance. Or try Integrate and then feature to polygon

Comment: the error was invalid topology [Z coord limit exceeded

Comment: If you dont need Z values copy the fc to a new one with z values disabled in environment settings

Comment: Thanks Bera that worked when running the tool but when I try using model builder I can't figure out how to set environments to disable, so close, but I'll keep looking on how to do that. That's my last hurdle. steps in MB...

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need [Feature Vertices To Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-vertices-to-points.htm).  It's available with an Advanced license of ArcGIS Desktop.

Comment: will the feature vertices to points also the vertices order and number them according to line segment? thx

Comment: The output vertices will retain the attributes of the input lines. They are not numbered  1 through "X" for each input feature, but they are processed in order of the how the input line(s) was drawn, so the object IDs of the output points will count up in order

Comment: so that isn't what I need but thx. I did find this --import arcpy

vals = []
fields = ['ORDER_ID', 'GROUP_ID'] #your field names
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(your_lyr, fields) as rows:
    for r in rows:
        vals.append(r[1])
        r[0] = vals.count(r[1])
        rows.updateRow(r)